# Call a bash function within a python script

Tags: python, bash, macos, subprocess

I have a `python` script (e.g. `test.py`) and a `commands.txt` file which contains a custom `bash` function (e.g. `my_func`) along with its parameters, e.g.

```
my_func arg1 arv2; my_func arg3 arg4; my_func arg5 arg6;
```

This function is included in the `~/.bash_profile`.
What I have tried to do is:

```
subprocess.call(['.', path/to/commands.txt], shell=True)
```

I know this is not the best case, in terms of setting the shell argument into True, but I cannot seem to implement it even in this way. What I get when I run `test.py` is:
`my_func: command not found`

Comment: Have you exported the function from your `.bash_profile`?  `export -f my_func`.  If you don't do that then it is only visible to the interactive session you define it in, i.e. it does not get passed to child processes.

Comment: @cdarke No, I haven't done that. Also, `my_func` uses other bash functions in its definition. Does this affect anything?

Comment: `subprocess.call(['for arg; do . "$arg"; done', '_', os.path.expanduser('~/.bashrc'), '/path/to/commands.txt'], shell=True)` will work, *if and only if* your scripts (`commands.txt` and `.bashrc`) are both compatible with `/bin/sh`.

Comment: @thanasissdr, ...you'll want to export both the function itself and its dependencies -- with that done, `subprocess.Popen(['bash', '-c', 'funcname "$@"', '_'] + args)` will be able to run it (with `args` being a Python list of arguments to pass to the function, ie. `args=['foo', 'bar', 'baz']` to run `funcname foo bar baz`). Using `bash` instead of `shell=True` makes sure you get a shell that actually knows how to read those exported functions, and passing arguments out-of-band from code is a security precaution: you don't want to pass a freeform field and have someone put `$(rm -rf ~)` in it.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thank you for the comment. Would it be possible to write a simple example?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to invoke bash directly, and instruct it to process both files.

At the command-line, this is:

```
bash -c '. ~/.bash_profile; . commands.txt'
```

Wrapping it in python:

```
subprocess.call(['bash', '-c', '. ~/.bash_profile; . commands.txt'])
```

You could also source ~/.bash_profile at the top of commands.txt.  Then you'd be able to run a single file.

It may make sense to extract the function to a separate file, since .bash_profile is intended to be used by login shells, not like this.

Comment: The function is  defined within the `~/.bash_profile`.

Comment: Updated to reflect this.  When you said  "I have a ... commands.txt file which contains a custom bash function (e.g. my_func)", I thought you meant that it contained the function definition.

Answer (score 0):

If the first line of your `commands.txt` file had the correct shebang (for example `#!/bin/bash`) making your file executable (`chmod +x commands.txt`) will be enough :

```
subprocess.call("path/to/commands.txt")
```

Comment: the extension `txt` doesn't matter?

Comment: @CedricJulien Thanks for the answer, is it possible to make the text file executable within the python script? `subprocess.call(['chmod +x', ' absolute/path/to/commands.txt'], shell=True)` would work as well?

Comment: @VanPeer Posix systems (like Linux) doesn't care of the extension

Comment: @thanasissdr yes, it could be possible

Comment: @CedricJulien I tried that but still I get the same error.

Comment: The above command is wrong in a *lot* of ways. `shell=True` runs the first element in your list as a script, with other contents as arguments *to the shell interpreter*. So `subprocess.call(['chmod +x "$@"', '_', '/path/to/file.txt'], shell=True)` will, for instance, work as a needlessly-inefficient way to run `subprocess.call(['chmod', '+x', '/path/to/file.txt'], shell=False)`.