# Execute a custom bash function within python

Tags: python, bash, macos, shell, subprocess

This question is a simpler version of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47184031/call-a-bash-function-within-a-python-script).

In simple terms, I have a custom bash function `my_func` defined on `~/.bash_profile` and uses two more bash functions defined in the same environment.

Also, `my_func` accepts two arguments, let's say `a` and `b`. What my_func does is that it gets connected to a remote server and sends some files (these are determined by `a` and `b`).

If I type on the `bash` shell:
`. my_func a b` everything works fine and I get some print statements on the screen.

However, if I include:
`subprocess.call(['#!/bin/bash . my_func a b'], shell=True)` nothing seems to happen.

I tried to export all the bash functions that are used by `my_func` by including:

`subprocess.call(['#!/bin/bash export -f my_func'], shell=True)` and I did the same for the rest of the functions that are used by `my_func`.

**EDIT:**

If I use `subprocess.call(['bash', '-c' ,'my_func a b], shell=True)` the bash shell will change into `bash-3.2$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to export the function *before* you start the python program:

```
export -f my_func
python foo.py
```

Well, the above example might not work if the system's default shell (/bin/sh) is not bash. To circumvent this, you may use subprocess call like this:

```
$ function foo() { echo "bar" ; }
$ export -f foo
$ cat foo.py
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['bash', '-c', 'foo'])
$ python foo.py
bar
```

---

**Alternative:**

I would put the function into a lib file, let's say:

```
# /usr/share/my_lib/my_lib.sh

function my_func() {
    # do something
}
```

Then I would expose the function via a script in PATH:

```
#!/bin/bash
# /usr/local/bin/my_prog

source /usr/lib/my_lib/my_lib.sh
my_func "$1" "$2"
```

In Python you would just:

```
subprocess.call(['/usr/local/bin/my_prog', 'a', 'b'])
```

Btw: If you don't need that function somewhere else, you can just put it directly into `/usr/local/bin/my_prog`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried to do that, but it didn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: Look carefully at the example. I'm **not** using `shell=True`

Comment: If I don't do that I do run into a lot of errors, like `ssh: command not found, basename:commnand not found, rsync: command not found` e.t.c. All these commands are included in the definition of `my_func`.

Comment: Hard to reproduce without seeing the function. Stupid question, why don't you simply put that function into a script, let's say `/usr/local/bin/my_script`  and just call that script? Wouldn't it be much simpler?

Comment: Great, this seems to be less complex. Thanks.